# java.sql.SQLException error caused by OpportunityLineItem DML request

Tags: trigger, java, opportunity-lineitem, error, opp-lineitemschedule

In our Salesforce.com organization, we have a trigger on the `OpportunityLineItem` object (insert/update), automatically generating `OpportunityLineItemSchedule`. The product is schedule by revenue, splitted using two dates available in the master `OpportunityLineItem` record (start/end date).

Everything is working fine, except when the `OpportunityLineItem` quantity is lower than `1` (like `0.25`). In this case, Salesforce is triggering this weird error:

> A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this
>   record. Contact your administrator to resolve it.
>   `java.sql.SQLException`: `ORA-20067`: `ORA-06512`: at "`GRUMPY.SOPPLINEITEM`",
>   line `1211` `ORA-06512`: at line `1`

Any idea what it means? I've been digging in the Salesforce log, but can't find much.

Comment: That sounds like something to contact SF Support about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@jpmonette, Congrats you've captured one of the 7 dwarves. (GRUMPY) So far as I know whenever you capture one of the 7 dwarves, all you can do is take a shot, and file a case with support.

Can you post example code that triggers the issue without, you know, giving away all the secret sauce your company pays you to develop? Perhaps with some code we can provide further advice.

Comment: I've captured DOPEY and SLEEPY as well, but that was years ago.

Comment: I've been troubleshooting with a Salesforce engineer. For some reason, the `UnitPrice` of my `OpportunityLineItem` ended up at `null`. It shouldn't be possible since this is a required field on Salesforce side. Can't wait to fix this awkward bug.

Comment: @jpmonette make sure to take a screen capture. The seven dwarves make for good war stories.

Comment: I contacted Salesforce two weeks ago and gave them access to a sandbox to test, with use case and showed the problem to a tech using GoToMeeting. Strangely, after 2 weeks without an answer, the Salesforce tech updated the case asking me for another use case since the first one wasn't working anymore. I checked, and I noticed the bug stopped happening (both in production and sandbox). I have no idea what was change, but I guess there was an update server-side that fixed it. Great!

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you get errors that refer to sql/oracle you're seeing errors which shouldn't be happening and are originating from logic internal platform. Salesforce keeps far more detailed log than exposed to us, most appropriate thing is to contact them through a support case