# Issue with web to lead

Tags: web2lead

Error I'm getting:

For more information about this error or help with Web-to-Case-Lead,
please contact Customer Support.

```
Reason: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-20096: ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.CUSER", line 3976 ORA-06512: at "DOPEY.SLEAD", line 1802 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

> {call
> sLead.update_leads(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
> ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
> ,?,?,?,?)}
>
> {call
> sLead.update_leads(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
> ,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
> ,?,?,?,?)}

Please suggest what could be the cause. I've checked and the leads are not being assigned/shared with any inactive user.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very low level system problem that you can't do anything about. You do indeed need to contact SF Support and file a case. For more on this error, see @kevenohara response to a question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/17914/2212) and also [Salesforce, Oracle and the Seven Dwarfs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76423/salesforce-oracle-and-the-seven-dwarfs/76779?s=2|0.1647#76779).